# MySQL subquery, alias, calculation from table joining query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, case, alias

Pretty new to `MySQL` here. I have the following query that isn't quite working the way I want: `**SELECT round(sum(temp_pop.pop_total * demographics.coefficient)) as demand, pop_proj.pop_total from pop_proj, d.age, d.coefficient, d.educationalattainment from demographics d JOIN (SELECT year,sum(pop_total), age FROM pop_proj GROUP BY year, age) AS temp_pop WHERE d.age = CASE WHEN temp_pop.age < 18 then '00 to 17' WHEN temp_pop.age > 64 then '65 to 80+' ELSE '18 to 64' end;**`

The sources are the `subquery` shown above in the syntax which I'm trying to `join` with a table called "`demographics`" with only three columns that shows `education level (educational attainment)`, an age range (age) - shown in the case statement, and a coefficient, used in the calculation at the beginning of the query. The pop_proj table provides a year, age, and population total (pop_total column). I'm trying to use temp_pop as an alias for the subquery. I'm fairly sure the case is written out correctly. However, when I run the query, it tells me this: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql> SELECT round(sum(temp_pop.pop_total * demographics.coefficient)) as deman' at line 1**

I also want to group the results by year and education level, I just haven't added that in there yet.

Previously I had it written only slightly differently and it was telling me it didn't recognize the column name pop_total, but haven't gotten a result without an error yet. I may be totally off on how write this query, but hoping I'm getting close. I would appreciate some help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you're really after but this may get you a step closer.

The below makes the assumption that you're relating `demographics` to `pop_total` only on the contrived age range string in your CASE which is suspicious and may not be valid.

This doesn't attempt to group the results, but that should be straightforward once you can see a working detailed output that meets your needs.

```
SELECT d.age, d.coefficient, d.educationalattainment, temp_pop.pop_total
FROM demographics d JOIN (
    SELECT `year`, age, sum(pop_total) as pop_total
    FROM pop_proj
    GROUP BY `year`, age
) temp_pop ON d.age = 
    CASE WHEN temp_pop.age < 18 THEN '00 to 17' 
    WHEN temp_pop.age > 64 THEN '65 to 80+' 
    ELSE '18 to 64' END
;
```

Comment: I just realized that I needed to add the "as pop_total" to declare that piece, so you're right. It's doing it right now. Thanks so much!